# Finding the data type of a scalar variable in Perl

Tags: perl

I have a function which accepts an input from the user. The input maybe an integer, a float or a string. I have three overloaded functions which should be called based on the DATA TYPE of the entered data. For example, if the user enters an integer (say 100), the function having integer parameter should be called. If the user enters a string (say "100") the function having the string parameter should be called.

So I need to find out the data type of the entered data. With regular expressions I am able to distinguish between an integer and a float (since I just need to find out the type, I wont prefer using the library provided at cpan.org), but I am not able to figure out how to differentiate an integer from a string. Perl treats "100" and 100 as the same? Is there any way to work around this problem?

Comment: Treating `"100"` and `100` the same is usually considered a feature of Perl. You need to explain better why it is a problem. What should happen when a user calls `your_function(100)` and how should it be different from when a user calls `your_function("100")`?

Comment: Ohk.. I thought of not going into the details of this. But since the situation demands: I got to call some C functions from inside perl. The functions are overloaded and present in my library. So I need to find out the type and invoke the correct version of the function EXPLICITLY.

Comment: Disregard my [deleted] answer. I misunderstood the intent of the question, and didn't realize you were talking about the "input" being physical arguments to functions.

Comment: if the user calls my_function(100), the function should call some C_int(100) while if the user calls as my_function("100"), the function should call, say C_string("100")

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From `perldoc perldata`:

> Scalars aren’t necessarily one thing or another.  There’s no place to declare a scalar variable to be of type "string", type "number", type "reference", or anything else.  Because of the automatic conversion of scalars, operations that return scalars don’t need to care (and in fact, cannot care) whether their caller is looking for a string, a number, or a reference.  Perl is a contextually polymorphic language whose scalars can be strings, numbers, or references (which includes objects).  Although strings and numbers are considered pretty much the same thing for nearly all purposes, references are strongly-typed, uncastable pointers with builtin reference-counting and destructor invocation.

So for integer scalars, you'll just need to decide ahead of time how you want to process them.  Perl will cheerfully convert from a number to a string or vice versa depending on the context.

Comment: Hmm thanks.. So I shouldnt be wasting my time on this and sort out some other approach to deal with it.. :D

Answer (score 10):

Perl does not make a useful distinction between numbers and string representations of those numbers.  Your script should not either.  You could write some code to differentiate between things that look like integers and floats, but the only way to know if it is a string is if the scalar does not look like an integer or a float.

Here is a simple routine that will return `int`, `rat`, or `str` for its argument.  Note that `100` and `'100'` are both `int`, but something like `'asdf'` will be `str`.

```
use Scalar::Util 'looks_like_number';
sub guess_type {
    looks_like_number($_[0]) ? $_[0] =~ /\D/ ? 'rat' : 'int' : 'str'
}

say guess_type 1;      # int
say guess_type "1";    # int
say guess_type 1.1;    # rat
say guess_type 'asdf'; # str
```

Since you are working on mapping Perl variables to C functions, you could write something like this:

```
sub myfunction {
    if (looks_like_number($_[0]) {
        if ($_[0] =~ /\D/) {C_float($_[0])}
        else               {  C_int($_[0])}
    }
    else {C_string($_[0])}
 }
```

Which should "do the right thing" when given a Perl scalar.  You may also want to add in a check to see if the argument is a reference, and then handle that case differently.

Comment: I don't agree with this at all: "Your script should not either." Just because a language doesn't do something doesn't imply that doing that thing is always wrong.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!perl6

use v6;

multi guess ( Int $a ) { say "got integer: $a" }
multi guess ( Str $a ) { say "got string: $a" }  
multi guess ( Rat $a ) { say "got float: $a" }

guess(3);
guess("3");
guess(3.0);
```

Cheating, I know...

Paul

Comment: sounds great!! Will definitely give it a try. By any chance, any such options or any other alternative with version 5??

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered passing the function a hash reference with the keys indicating what datatype the input is?

```
my $str_input = { string => "100" };
my $int_input = { integer => 100 };
my $float_input = { float => 100.0 };
```

You can check what type you got by checking which key the input has:
`my $datatype = shift (keys %{$input})` and take it from there. (Note the implicit dereferencing happening to `$input`)

```
switch ($datatype) {
   case string:
       C_string($input->{$datatype});
   case integer:
       C_integer($input->{$datatype});
   case float:
       C_float($input->{$datatype});
}
```