# Perl. Check if scalar's value is zero number

Tags: perl

I need to check if scalar's value is 0. But '0' and other situations are false for my checking. How could I check it?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  What are you trying?  What isn't working for you?  What do you expect to happen?

Comment: I have some function. I pass a scalar to this function. It should return true only if scalar contains a NUMBER 0. not a STRING '0' or something other, only if it is a NUMBER.

Comment: I'm not sure that Perl is the right language for you.  Perl just automatically switches between text and number interpretation based on the context.

Comment: I know Perl does it. But I need to do and need to check.

Comment: show your code, what are you trying to do?

Comment: In Perl, it's bad practice to consider how the number is stored to be meaninful. IV 0 should be considered the same as PV 0.

Comment: What do you want to return when the scalar contains both?

Comment: so maybe you shouldn't be doing it in Perl...  Anyway, could you please clarify the question?  Also note that strings and numbers are both scalars, so I'm not sure that using 'scalar' in the title is correct.

Comment: Please see this:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6361696/finding-the-data-type-of-a-scalar-variable-in-perl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***If you only care about "0"...***

Use a string comparison.

```
if($a eq "0") {
     print("Zero!");
} else {
     print("Not zero!");
}
```

If you simply set `my $a;`, then `if($a == 0)` will return `true`, when what we want out of it is to return `false`.

By using a string comparison, you can definitively check.

***If you care about "0.0", "000", etc...***

If you're worried about values like `0.00`, or `000`, you can `split('', $string)`, uniq the pieces, rejoin them, and then compare for "0." or "0", like...

```
my $simplestring = join('', uniq split('', $number));
if($simplestring eq '0.' || $simplestring eq '0') {
     print("Zero!");
} else {
     print("Not zero!");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can check if a scalar's value is zero using

```
$scalar == 0
```

You really shouldn't, but you can check if the scalar contains an IV (signed int), UV (unsigned int) or NV (floating point number) with value zero using:

```
use Inline C => <<'__END_OF_C__';

   IV contains_numerical_zero(SV* sv) {
      SvGETMAGIC(sv);

      if (SvIOKp(sv))  /* If the SV contains an IV or UV */
         return SvIV(sv) == 0;

      if (SvNOKp(sv))  /* If the SV contains an NV */
         return SvNV(sv) == 0;

      return 0;
   }

__END_OF_C__

say contains_numerical_zero(...) ? "yes" : "no";
```

Note that the `contains_numerical_zero` returns true if the scalar contains both a signed int equal to zero and a string consisting the character zero.

Answer (score 1):

From the comments on your question, I understand that you want to know if perl thinks the scalar is a number or a string. This can be done using the [Devel::Peek](http://search.cpan.org/~ilyaz/Devel-Peek-0.96/Peek.pm) module.

```
use Devel::Peek 'Dump';

$a = 0;
Dump $a;
```

This will print:

```
SV = IV(0x6750a8) at 0x6750b8
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (IOK,pIOK)
  IV = 0
```

Whereas:

```
$b = '0';
Dump $b;
```

will print:

```
SV = PV(0x654c20) at 0x675058
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (POK,pPOK)
  PV = 0x66e110 "0"\0
  CUR = 1
  LEN = 16
```

Comment: However: `perl -MDevel::Peek -e '$x = "0"; $y = $x + 1; Dump $x;'` prints `SV = PVIV(0x...`, as does `perl -MDevel::Peek -e '$x = 0; $y = $x . ""; Dump $x;'`. A scalar is not _either_ string _or_ numeric as the OP seems to be assuming. It can be both simultaneously if it has been used in both contexts.